# How to set the <td> width of h:selectOneRadio

Tags: html, css, jsf

http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_selectOneRadio.html

How to set the  width of h:selectOneRadio using the styleClass attribute, I would like to enforce a similar width for all  elements within the above radio button group.

Comment: Open JSF page in browser, rightclick and choose *View Source*, and open your eyes. It's all just plain vanilla HTML! You can just base your CSS on that. The `h:selectOneRadio` indeed renders (as documented...) a `<table>`. You just have to style the `<td>` elements.

Comment: I wasn't sure of how to apply the style to the buttons for this styleClass alone. If I knew, I wouldn't be asking the question ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine that you have this kind of code:

```
<h:form id="foo">
    <h:selectOneRadio id="bar" value="#{...}">
        ...
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    ...
```

Then, in your CSS, you can try to do that:

```
table#foo\:bar > td {
    width: 42px;
}
```

or

```
table#foo\:bar > tr > td {
    width: 42px;
}
```

or

```
table#foo\:bar td {
    width: 42px;
}
```

(I don't remember exactly how the parent relationship in CSS work, that's why I suggest these three examples)

In CSS, it means *affect a 42px width to all elements `<td>` that have a `<tr>` parent, which have a `<table>` parent with the ID `foo:bar`*

Comment: The colon `:` is indeed an illegal identifier in CSS. You need to escape it by backslash, i.e. `table#foo\:bar`.

Comment: @BalusC You're totally right. I remember that I used that more than one year ago because I encountered this problem ;)